# What is the name of translate language menu control from Google Chrome's Android browser and how to implement it?

Tags: android, google-chrome, xamarin, menu, xamarin.forms

I noticed the menu on the bottom side of Google Chrome's Android web browser application. It is used for setting language for translation of pages. Can you help me identify what is this control's name?

[image]

I'm currently working on Xamarin.Forms project and would like to implement similar menu on the bottom side of my screen for all Android devices. Is that possible in Xamarin.Forms and how would the implementation look like?

Comment: it is a radiogroup with custom radiobuttons. Or maybe it is just a TabLayout.

Comment: TabLayout can be only on the top of the screen and this one happens to be on the bottom. On the other side, RadioButton is unfortunately not a Xamarin.Forms control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm currently working on Xamarin.Forms project and would like to implement similar menu on the bottom side of my screen for all Android devices. Is that possible in Xamarin.Forms and how would the implementation look like?

There is no direct control in xamarin.forms that can serve this purpose. So you will need your own [Custom View](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view/) for this:

1. In PCL, create a custom control class(`MyTabLayout`):

   ```
   public class MyTabLayout:View
   {
   }
   ```
2. In PCL page, using this control in Xaml:

   ```
   <StackLayout>
       <!--EndAndExpand will bottom the tab control-->
       <local:MyTabLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"></local:MyTabLayout>
   </StackLayout>
   ```
3. In `YourProject.Android` project Create your custom renderer:

   ```
   [assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomTabsLayout.MyTabLayout),
   typeof(MyTabLayoutRenderer))]
   namespace CustomTabsLayout.Droid
   {
       public class MyTabLayoutRenderer:ViewRenderer<MyTabLayout,TabLayout>
       {
           Context baseContext;
           public MyTabLayoutRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
           {
               baseContext = context;
           }

           protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyTabLayout> e)
           {
               base.OnElementChanged(e);
               //Below are test tabs, you can customize your tabs' styles here.
               TabLayout tab = new TabLayout(baseContext);
               tab.AddTab(tab.NewTab().SetText("tab1"));
               tab.AddTab(tab.NewTab().SetText("tab2"));
               tab.AddTab(tab.NewTab().SetText("tab3"));
               tab.AddTab(tab.NewTab().SetText("tab4"));
               tab.AddTab(tab.NewTab().SetText("tab5"));

               SetNativeControl(tab);
           }

       }
   }
   ```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution with me. I managed to implement custom renderer in Xamarin.Forms project.